# Is everything right here in this proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $p$ be a prime number.

Suppose that $x^2=p$ and that $x$ is rational so that we have $x=\dfrac {a}{b}$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb N$ (it does not matter which representatives for $a,b$ we choose).

So we have $x^2+x=p+\dfrac {a}{b}=\dfrac {pb+a}{b} \iff bx^2+bx-bp=a \implies b |a$ , so $x \in \mathbb N$, which is not possible because if possible then $x^2$ would have more than two divisors, that is at least three: $1$ and $x$ and $x^2$, so $x^2$ wouldn`t then be a prime.

> Is everything OK with this proof? Are there some inconsistencies that I do not see?

Comment: You can conclude from $x \in \mathbb{N}$ that $x$ is $0$ or $1$, which is not possible since $x^2$ is not a prime in these cases.  This is basically how you conclude, just said differently.

Comment: how do you know that $b\,|\,a$?  We have $b(x^2+x-p)=a$ of course, but $x^2+x-p=\frac ab$ isn't assumed to be an integer.

Comment: `bx^2+bx−bp=a ⟹ b|a` This step does not hold because the LHS is $b \cdot (x^2+x-p)$ but what's inside the parenthesis is only known to be rational, not an integer, so it does not follow that $b \mid a\,$.

Comment: @Randall Right, thought about that. So all is right?

Comment: @lulu Now I see, can we modify this approach to work?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen I believe the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is necessary for this. So no, this approach seems flawed unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see how.  More to the point, I don't know of any reason why the case of prime  $p$ should be isolated.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Sufficient yes, but necessary, why?

Comment: The end result is $bx^2 + bx -bp = a$ but as $bx = a$ and $bx^2 = bp$, I honestly do not see anything salvageable in this.

Comment: "Sufficient yes, but necessary, why"  Well, I don't see what else we *have*.  The only such proof that doesn't use FTA is that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational which uses that all number are either even or odd and odd squares must be odd. (so $2b^2 = a^2$ mean $a$ and $b$ are both even.) The only equivalent is that $pb^2 = a^2$ mean $a,b$ are both divisible by $p$ but *only* if we prove non-p-factor squares are non-p-factors. which requires either i)FTA or ii) testing *all* $k^2; 1\le k \le p$.  ii) is impossible so i) is necessary..

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look right. You cannot conclude that $bx^2+bx-bp=a $ implies $b|a $ because $x $ is (by that point) still a rational number, you don't know (yet) that it is an integer.

Example: $2\times 1+2\times\frac {1}{2}=3$ but $3$ is not divisible by $2$.

Comment: Can we modify somehow to make it work?

Comment: I would leave it up to you... Happy to review the modified proof, of course.

Comment: Oh, this is a great point.